# Get more descriptive errors from Windows and Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-errors

[image: In Eclipse]

[image: In Visual Studio]

How can I have Visual Studio show me details like in Eclipse when errors occur? is this simply a debugging feature that needs to be turned on (selected) or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe because it's a more important error :/ `while(true)` is a really bad idea you should better put a boolean that will stay true.

You should have the error you do appear on the back of the screen.

Comment: yes well its not even my code, I was helping someone debug and did notice that her Windows did not give descriptive errors.